# Vetur + Prettier HTML formatter

Tags: html, prettier, vetur

I'm using Quasar with Vue3 and the vs code extension Vetur and Prettier to help me keep the code well formatted.

I see something I don't really like and I would like to fix it in the configuration, but I cannot find the solution, so I hope you can help me.

The current HTML formatter generate this code:

```
<q-btn
   unelevated
   color="secondary"
   type="submit"
   class="full-width"
   >Sign in</q-btn
>
```

I don't really like to see this: `>Text</close`, instead, I would like it to be like this:

```
<q-btn
   unelevated
   color="secondary"
   type="submit"
   class="full-width"
>
   Sign in
</q-btn>
```

So that the element and the text are on different lines.

Can you please drive me to the solution? Thanks

Comment: if you are using vue 3 use `volar` as `vetur` is no longer recommended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is not possible to do what you want because `prettier` (or even `eslint`, `volar`) cannot determine whether now or in the future an element will be able to parent another element if you having a `Node` but not a `Text` inside such formatting changes a lot of things:

When you enter a newline then `\n` will definitely appear because it is `Text` so by default it is rendered as `Node<Text>` which doesn't sound bad but look at the example below:

```js
app.appendChild(document.createElement('div'))
app2.appendChild(document.createElement('div'))


console.log('child of default: %s', app.childNodes.length)
console.log('child of you format: %s', app2.childNodes.length)
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<div id="app2">
</div>
```

you will find that adding anything in front of it destroys the expected DOM structure. it is so awful

to fix it you can add `space` after `>` of the opening tag because `space` or `space - new line` it is just 1 `Node<Text>` only nothing is affected